# How to use TeamCity parameters to swap out values from a .csx file

Tags: c#, teamcity

we are using a .csx file to store certain parameters for our UI Automation solution such as the browser we want the tests to run on and the Selenium Grid URL. We are also using TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.3 (build 42434) to build and run our tests. I've had a look on the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Build+Parameters) but don't really understand how to do it.

Question: How do I configure the build to use parameters to swap out the values stored in the CSX file?

Here is my CSX file (called SettingsData.csx):

```
string BrowserValue = "chrome";
string BrowserMobileValue = "Samsung Galaxy S4";

string DeviceValue = "Samsung Galaxy S4";
string EnvironmentValue = "Live";

string FeatureBranchValue = "";
string FeatureIdValue = "";

string GridUrlValue = "http://IE-SLM-HUB:5555/wd/hub";

string PlatformValue = "";
string ResolutionValue = "default";

string ScreenWidthValue = "1280";
string ScreenHeightValue = "960";

Dictionary<string, object> SeleniumGridSetupValue = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"browserName", "chrome"}
    };

Dictionary<string, object> SeleniumGridMobileSetupValue = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"browserName", "chrome"}
    };
```

If anyone can provide an example of how I use parameters to swap out one of these values I would greatly appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do this, this wouldn't be using parameters at all but would use **Build Features** and the **File Content Replacer** feature. Pretty simple to use, you set the file path of the file you want values replaced and a Regex of the initial value and the goal value.